# Facebook Graph API - My access token fails for 1% of public Event requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using my `FACEBOOK_APP_ID|FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET` access token to get events data from facebook.

- It works for 99% of events :)
- But, it fails on 1%, even though **they are public events**
- I cannot spot any difference between the events that fail and those that succeed.
- when trying in the [FB Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=481398338716859%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cstart_time%2Ccover%2Cplace%2Cdescription%2Cowner%2Ctype&version=v2.7), these requests work fine with the default access token, but do not work with my access token.
- the same events work/dont-work with my token in the Graph Explorer as in my php code.
- I've tried creating a new facebook application with new access token and the same behaviour occurs.

This event, like almost all, works with my token:

> https://www.facebook.com/events/1358567590825431/

This event doesn't work:

> https://www.facebook.com/events/481398338716859/
>
> Graph returned an error: Unsupported get request. Object with ID
>   '481398338716859' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
>   permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
>   API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Is this a bug with facebook or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The latter is not a public event; I am trying to access both pages without being logged in, and the first one works, while the second one takes me to a 404-like page.

Comment: interesting - through the graph it returns type as "public"